# Decrease Vertical Space in Aligned environment

Tags: math-mode, align

How can one have control over the vertical space brought on by a `\\` for the new aligned entry in the `aligned` environment?

For example, how to I condense the following?

```
$\begin{aligned}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{aligned}$
```

I am using this through the `btex-etex` environment in metapost and `\begin{group}` does not seem to do it!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Answer (score 7):

You mean like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  $\begin{aligned}
    a & b \\[-2\jot]  %% or [-1ex] Change 2\jot or -1ex as you like
    c & d
    \end{aligned}
  $
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another method is to add `\openup-2\jot` just before `\begin{aligned}` as mentioned by egreg (thanks to him for letting me know this).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  $ \openup-2\jot
  \begin{aligned}
    a & b \\  
    c & d
    \end{aligned}
  $
\end{document}
```

Comment: Or `\openup-2\jot` just before `\begin{aligned}`.

Comment: That's a “Plain TeXism”, which happens to work also with `amsmath`.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution with the `stackengine` package; you can't easily change the vertical spacing, but it has a simpler syntax. This code lets you compare:

```
\documentclass{article}

 \usepackage{mathtools}
 \usepackage{stackengine} 

 \begin{document}

\verb+\Vectorstack:+\\[-10.3pt]
\mbox{} \hspace{4em}$ \Vectorstack{ab cd} \hspace{4em} \begin{array}{cc}
\verb+With aligned:+ & \verb+Aligned with correction:+\\
 \begin{aligned} a & b \\ c & d \end{aligned} & \begin{aligned} a & b \\[-2\jot] c & d \end{aligned}\\
 \end{array} $

 \end{document}
```

[image]